# Equivalente ao NPM I para o Expo em React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Quando eu desenvolvo uma aplicação que requer o NodeJS em local ai se eu precisar ir para outro local e continuar meu projeto preciso dar o seguinte comando:

```
 npm i ou npm install
```

QUando uma aplicação é feita em React-Native tem o [Expo](https://expo.io/).

Exite algum equivalente ao npm i para expo?

Para que instale todas as depenencias do expo no meu projeto?

Porque ja dei `npm i` baixou as dependências, mas tive que rodar o `expo install alguma coisa`, para instalar dependencias dele

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O comando `expo install` pode ser usado para instalar todas as dependências de um projeto. Ele envolve o `npm` e o `yarn` de maneira que consiga garantir que a versão dos pacotes das comunidades Expo SDK e React Native a serem instalados sejam compatíveis com o seu aplicativo.

Essas informações estão no [Walkthrough](https://docs.expo.io/introduction/walkthrough/) do Expo.

Comment: Então posso dar também o `expo install` de boa?

Comment: Sim. No Walkthrough tem um exemplo disponível para realizar o download e é dito para usar o `expo install` para que todas dependências sejam instaladas :)